# Let $F$ be a field and let $R$ be the $F$-subalgebra of $F[x]$ generated by $x^2$ and $x^3.$ Show that $R$ is not a unique factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> $1.$ Let $F$ be a field and let $R$ be the integral domain in $F[x]$ generated by $x^2$ and $x^3.$ Show that $R$ is not a unique factorization domain

**Attempt:** $R = \langle x^3,x^2 \rangle = \{p(x)~ x^3 + q(x)~x^2~~|~~p(x),q(x) \in F[x]\}$

I think we need to find an element in $R$ with more than one factorization. However, at the moment, I am not able to think of one. Please tell me how do I find one.

> $2.$ In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-7]}$, show that $6+2 \sqrt{-7}$ and $1+3 \sqrt{-7}$ are not associated.

**Attempt:** Suppose $6+2 \sqrt{-7} = u~(1+3 \sqrt{-7})$ . We need to show that $u$ is not a unit. But $N(1+3 \sqrt{-7})=N(6+2 \sqrt{-7}) =64 \implies N(u)=1$ which is possible if and only if $u$ is a unit $\implies$ the two quantities must be associates.

Where could I be making a mistake?

> $3.$ Prove or disprove that a sub domain of a Euclidean domain is a Euclidean Domain.

**Attempt:** Every Euclidean Domain is a principal ideal domain which means every Euclidean domain is a unique factorization domain as well.

So, if we prove that there exists a sub domain of a Euclidean domain which is not a unique factorization domain, then we are sure that a sub domain of a Euclidean domain is not a Euclidean domain.

Or we prove that every every sub ring of an Euclidean domain is a Euclidean domain, then we can prove it. Somewhere, I feel that this could be true.

If $d$ is the measure , A Euclidean domain $D$ satisfies : $(i) d(a) \leq d(ab)~\forall~a,b \in D$

$(ii)$ If $a =bq+r$, then $d(b) > d(r)$.

I think every sub ring of a Euclidean domain satisfies this? Hence, every sub domain of a Euclidean domain must be Euclidean

Am I correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1. gives example for   "disprove" in 3.

Comment: 1. Use UFDs are integrally closed.

Comment: If $d$ is the measure , A Euclidean domain $D$ satisfies : $(i) d(a) \leq d(ab)~\forall~a,b \in D$

$(ii)$ If $a =bq+r$, then $d(b) > d(r)$.

I think every sub ring of a Euclidean domain satisfies this? Hence, every sub domain of a Euclidean domain must be Euclidean

Is my argument not right?

Comment: Ohh I think the division algorithm must be legal in the sub domain as well. Hence, $Z[x]$ is not a Euclidean domain as division algorithm is not valid but $Q[x]$ is one. Hence, my argument does not stand. Am I Correct?

Comment: Right, if $a,b$ are in a subdomain, the quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ need not be as well, so there's no guarantee the division algorithm holds for the subdomain.

Comment: For (1): $x^6 = (x^2)^3 = (x^3)^2$; show that $x^2, x^3$ are irreducible in $R$

Comment: @zcn spoilsport!

Comment: @blue: The fun is in showing irreducibility!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) $\langle x^2,x^3\rangle$ in $F[x]$ is not an integral domain because it's missing an identity. The ring we're talking about is $R=F[x^2,x^3]$ (or $K[x^2,x^3]$ where $K$ is the prime subfield, it doesn't really matter). Have you considered something that's $=$ to a product of $x^2$s or $x^3$s?

(2) You're assuming $u$ is an element of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-7}]$. Simplify $\frac{6+2\sqrt{-7}}{1+3\sqrt{-7}}$ to find it's not in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-7}]$ because every element of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-7}]$ has a **unique** representation as $a+b\sqrt{-7}$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Q$.

(3) The issue is that if $a,b$ are in a subdomain of an ED, the quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ in any division expression $a=bq+r$ need not be in the subdomain as well. An ED would be a UFD as you note, so it'd suffice to find a subdomain of an ED which is not a UFD, and you've already done this (see (1)).

Comment: Thank you :-). I  just had a query in $(1)$. So, $R = F[x^2,x^3]$. uhmm, I am not sure what that means actually.

Comment: @VHP you don't know what the notation $F[a,b]$ means? It's the ring of $F$-coefficient polynomials in $a$ and $b$. That means $F[x^2,x^3]$ has any polynomial $f(x^2,x^3)$ in it.

Comment: oh ohk .. my bad.. I understand the notation