# Unique Factoring in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

While in class, my professor gave us a proposition that if $R$ is a unique factoring domain, then $R[x]$ is also a unique factoring domain. While in class I didn't think too much about it, but now I think I don't understand what he meant because of the following example:
$$x^6=x^3 \cdot x^3$$ $$x^6=x^4 \cdot x^2$$
Clearly, these factorizations aren't unquie, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is a unique factoring domain, so shouldn't $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be? Is it the case I simply wrote the theorem down incorrectly, or am I misunderstanding what it means to be a unique factorization domain?

Comment: Well if you accept $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, why isn't $64=2^6$ a contradiction for $8*8=16*4$? It's a good question you're asking, but I suggest you refer back to the definition you were given or look it up first.

Comment: The two factorizations you give for $x^6$ are considered the same factorization. Take another look at the precise statement of the theorem in your textbook, or the Wikipedia article for Unique Factorization Domain, or the Wolfram Mathworld article for Unique Factorization.

Comment: $x$ is prime in $\Bbb Z[x]$ so it is analogous to $\, p^3 p^3 = p^4 p^2\,$ for a prime  $p\in\Bbb Z,\,$ which have unique prime factorization $p^6.\,$ The terms $p_i^{e_i}$ in the unique factorization must have prime $p_i$ that are *distinct* (or, more generally, non-associate).

Comment: Once you absorb the information in the above comments and understand why these are not distinct factorizations of $x^6$ in this ring, you might be interested in seeing [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/885363/29335) which uses the same characters in a subring that does not have unique factorization.